# What can come after phrase "as well as"?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

I am trying to understand the usage of word as. I came across the following sentence.

> He is an excellent teacher as well as being a fine musician.

Is it incorrect to write as follows?

> 1. He is an excellent teacher as well as a fine musician.
> 2. He is an excellent teacher as well as is a fine musician.

I have a feeling number 1 is correct, but not sure about number 2. 
I read in *Practical English Usage* that this is a correct way of writing:

> I have to feed the animals as well as look after the children.

In short, can number 2 be used and not be marked grammatically incorrect?

Comment: *1) He is an excellent teacher as well as a fine musician.* is correct. I am unable to exactly point out the reason though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as-well-as) explains "as well as":

> **As well as** is a multi-word preposition which means ‘in addition to’:
>
> - She has invited Jill **as well as** Kate.
> - When they go to Austria, they like walking **as well as** skiing.

It is good to take into account that using "as well as" requires you to pay attention to [**parallelism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)). That is why your example:

> 2. He is an excellent teacher as well as is a fine musician.

is not correct.

It should be either:

> He is an excellent teacher as well as a fine musician.

(like your example 1) or:

> He is an excellent teacher as well as **he** is a fine musician.

Answer (score 0):

We see in these examples the following pattern:

> [subject] [verb] [argument1] as well as [argument2]

In the example from *Practical English Usage*, the [verb] is the auxiliary *have to*. It could have been *have to feed*, if the part after the *as well* were a valid argument to *feed*, but it isn't. So it could have been:

> I have to feed the animals as well as the children

In that case, *I have to feed* would distribute over *the animals* and *the children*, meaning:

> I have to feed the animals and I have to feed the children.

The *PEU* example means:

> I have to feed the animals and I have to look after the children

Here, the verb *have to* is distributed over the two arguments, each of which is a verb phrase.

The sentence you are concerned about means:

> He is an excellent teacher and he is a fine musician.

Obviously, there is a shared *is* in this sentence, so we can take that out and distribute it over the two arguments, *an excellent teacher* and *a fine musician*:

> He is an excellent teacher as well as a fine musician.

The verb appears after *as well as* in the *PEU* example because the argument to *have to* is a verb phrase, while in the teacher example the argument to *is* is a noun phrase.